# How do I prevent React.lazy from rendering a fallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm importing my dashboard page like this:

```
const Dashboard = React.lazy(
  () => import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ "./pages/Dashboard")
);
```

When my app loads, the login page is displayed, and immediately the dashboard page starts loading in the background. It will *practically always* be loaded before the user logs in, so I don't want to display a fallback before the dashboard page is displayed.

Currently what happens is:

1. The user loads the login page
2. The dashboard page is almost immediately loaded in the background
3. The user types their username and password and presses "Log in"
4. A spinner is displayed while the server checks their credentials
5. When the user is redirected to the dashboard page, React immediately renders the fallback component (the text "Loading") and then immediately replaces it with the dashboard component. This is perceived as a white flicker for the user.

If I log out and back in (without reloading the page), the flicker does not occur. If I bundle the dashboard normally, without using lazy loading, the flicker does not occur.

Is there any way to inform React that there's *no need to display a fallback*, since the page is already loaded? Currently it's just rendering the fallback and immediately rendering the page, which is pointless.

---

Ideally, I would like the fallback to be rendered if the dashboard page still hasn't loaded, but if the dashboard page is loaded in the background before it's rendered, it should act *exactly* as if it was included in the initial bundle.

I'd be more than happy with being able to disable rendering the fallback altogether though.

Comment: I think it's default behaviour of `code-splitting` - https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: @ravibagul91 yes it's default behavior but even though it's bizarre that when the component is fully loaded, React shows fallback for a second.

Comment: I just created a sample app to test it, and what I noticed is that the lazy-loaded page is being loaded when the route matches with it. Before that, it's not loaded in a background, therefore the fallback is displayed. Afterward, a page is visible in a cache, in turn, fallback does not appear.

Comment: @TomaszCzechowski If you include the `/* webpackPrefetch: true */` comment from my answer, the browser will pre-load the module in the background while the app is initializing. You can confirm this by watching the dev tools network tab when you reload the page. When React tries to load the module, it's loaded instantly from cache, so it's pointless to display the fallback.